# In Three.js, how might one be able to detect compile errors in shader code?

Tags: three.js, webgl, shader, glsles

I'm building off a project in three.js and one of the ideas I'm fiddling around with would allow users to write their own shader code. Code from the user would dynamically load to the gpu, much like in [this example](http://glsl.heroku.com/e). In such a setup, the user would benefit greatly from having some way to display compile time errors generated by his code. I've looked into the code from the above example, but this instance works directly with WebGl.

Are there any alternatives I might consider that leverage the three.js library to detect compile time shader errors?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing but it looks like what you'd want to do is use WebGL to compile and link the shaders. If there are errors display them. If compiling and linking was successful then make [a  three.js ShaderMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/materials/ShaderMaterial) and pass in the shader source that just worked.

If you view-source on [glsl.heroku.com/e](https://github.com/mrdoob/glsl-sandbox/blob/master/static/index.html) you can see in the `createShader` code it checks for errors and attempts to highlight specific lines in the source.